# UITableView Load more without reload complete table

Tags: performance, uitableview, scroll, flicker, smooth-scrolling

What is the better option to add new rows at the end in UITableView to maintain smooth scrolling.

Option 1 - insertRowsAtIndexPaths
Option 2 - reloadData

If I use reloadData, UITableView flickers for a seconds and affect smooth scrolling.

I am trying to implement "Load more" feature in the UITableView while user scrolls table to the bottom. Web service is used to get data using asynchronous calls for Load More rows.

Comment: Option 1 - insertRowsAtIndexPaths is better option for load more. You can add animation also.

Comment: Could you please help us in providing few lines of code to implement insertRowsAtIndexPaths

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: Kindly accept the answer if it is helpful. This is the motivation for us.

Comment: have you ever tried the given solution ?. Actually I was aware about the implementation but I am looking some confirmation on the basis of actual implementation. We have some complex code structure with common component once I implement it and if it improve performance definitely I will accept your answer. Thanks

Comment: Yes I implemented this solution on my app, and it works fine. Atleast you can upvote.

Answer (score 3):

Add this code where you are getting webservice response.

```
 NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSInteger currentCount = self.datasource.count;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataToAdd.count; i++) {
        [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:currentCount+i inSection:0]];
    }

    // do the insertion
    [self.dataSource addObjects:dataToAdd];

    // tell the table view to update (at all of the inserted index paths)
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
```